# Is it possible to highlight the background of methods, for loops, while loops etc.?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've recently tried to switch from Bluej (we used that in school) to eclipse (which seems to be way more widespread) but I have some trouble distinguishing between different loops and methods etc. I am used to everything being highlighted. Is there a way to make it [look like in BlueJ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3SYK.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be you should ask [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: You may be comfortable with the colour, but why not try being uncomfortable? Your code is indented, so you have visual structure; try without, and you will quickly find you don't need the extra colour.

Comment: This is the first I’ve seen of this ever. We were initially taught in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) is another widely used IDE if you're willing to switch to it, it also has a [BlueJ plugin](https://bluej.org/netbeans/). However, it's only available for NetBeans 6.5